# C++ GetModuleFileName using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code that needs to be ported from windows to boost:

```
BOOL Class::fn_GetModulePath(WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH])
{
    BOOL bReturn = FALSE;

    dll::library_handle hDll = dll::load_shared_library((const char*)DC_DLL_FILENAME);
    //HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(DC_DLL_FILENAME);
    
    if (hDll)
    {
        // This function needs replacing
        DWORD dwResult = GetModuleFileName(hDll,szPath,MAX_PATH);

        dll::close_shared_library(hDll);
        //FreeLibrary(hDll);

        if (dwResult)
        {
            int iLen = (int) wcslen(szPath);

            if (iLen)
            {
                for (int i = iLen; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if(szPath[i] == '\\')
                    {
                        szPath[i+1] = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            bReturn = TRUE;
        }
    }

    return bReturn;
}
```

How would I go about implementing the `GetModuleFileName` function using Boost?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a shared library know where it resides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563643/how-can-a-shared-library-know-where-it-resides)

Comment: @Botje No, sadly it does not.

Comment: Where/how is this dll::library_handle type defined?

Comment: namespace dll = boost::extensions::impl;
And then the library_handle type from boost

Comment: There is no `library_handle` identifier in my copy of boost.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::dll::shared_library` class has a method `location` which returns the full path to the library.

For the whole program, there is `boost::dll::program_location` global function.

In addition, it is possible to find the executable or library location by symbol address and by source location:

```
boost::dll::symbol_location
boost::dll::this_line_location
```

The latter can only be used by a module to find its own location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Boost.Dll`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/dll/shared_library.html) like so:

```
shared_library lib(DC_DLL_FILENAME);
filesystem::path full_path = lib.location();
```

If you're trying to get the path to the currently running code, that is `boost::dll::this_line_location()`.